# update table column if provided text is not matched

Tags: mysql, update

I want to update a huge table, I can do the below in PHP but it will take longer time I believe.

```
$string = "test string";
if($string!="Amazon.com"){
//set table column value as FBA
}

if($string=="Amazon.com"){
//set table column value as AMZ
}
```

Can I do this via MYSQL query ?

thanks

Comment: Where the "test srting" is stored?

Comment: column name is "merchantDetails"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update all your table with query:

```
UPDATE table 
   SET value = IF(merchantDetails = "Amazon.com", "AMZ", "FBA");
```

where `table` and `value` should be changed to the actual names of table and field.

Comment: Query OK, 452176 rows affected (1 min 21.01 sec)
Rows matched: 2484974  Changed: 452176  Warnings: 0